# ASP.NET - losing selection of dropdownlist populated via javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, drop-down-menu

I have two ASP.NET dropdownlist controls on a page. The first calls back to the server and obtains an array which is returned to the client and used to populate the second dropdownlist via javascript.
However if I make a selection in the second (and newly populated) dropdownlist and then do a postback the selection and contents of the second dropdownlist are lost. This is an issue since I need to obtain the selected value and have the contents of the list retained after the postback.

How do I fix this? I presume it's a matter of updating viewstate at some point before the postback?

---

The controls I'm populating are ASP.NET dropdownlists. Here is the the javascript I'm using to populate them.

Code being used is as follows (slightly cut down for brevity):

**ASP.NET control I'm populating:**

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateCounty" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStateCounty_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

**Call back code that obtains comma separated list of values:**

```
public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
    return "1, 2, 3";
}
```

**Javascript population code:**

```
function ReceiveServerData(retValue)
{ 
    var statesArray = retValue.split(',');
    var statesList = document.getElementById('{0}');

    if (statesArray.length > 0 && statesList != null)
        {
                for (var j = 0; j < statesArray.length; j++)
            {
                    var newOption = document.createElement('OPTION');
                        statesList.options.add(newOption);
            newOption.value = statesArray[j].toString().trim();
                    newOption.innerText = statesArray[j];
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your aspx page, javascript code and codebehind (in 3 separate code blocks would be good) :)

Answer (score 6):

You're correct in stating that you don't have the ViewState right, which is why the values aren't populated when you post the data back to the server.

I would **strongly** recommend that you migrate to using the [Cascading Drop Down](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) within the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit (it has both .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 releases), as it does what you are after and it **does** maintain via the postback.

Your other option would be to have an `onchange` event on the JavaScript-populated drop down list in which you then populate a hidden field, as that will be posted back to the server and the value of the submit will be maintained within the posted data, something like:

```
$addHandler('change', $get('dynamicDDL'), function () { $get('hiddenField').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; });
```

*For the demo I used the MS AJAX short-hand for adding events, etc. More info on the methods I used can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb397536.aspx*

Answer (score 3):

Request.Form[Control.UniqueID] gives you the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

just use response.forms collection to get the selected value.

Comment: Thanks! However I also need to be able to retain the values of the dropdownlist between posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that "you aren't doing things the asp.net way".

It seems likely to me that if your javascript modifications aren't native asp.net then the elements you're populating aren't asp.net controls so you're losing them in the postback. asp.net really demands a tight binding between it's model and the actual page.

Could be way off base though - would help if you could post some code. (the JS and the codebehind method)

**edit for new info:**

Right - so you're basically creating a load of perfectly normal html elements through JS alone based on an AJAXified return string(?), which the asp.net codebehind has *no concept of whatsoever*. I'm not 100% sure this is the problem without setting up a test app myself, but it sounds about right.

Inspecting Request.Forms then - as others have suggested - is going to be the simplest way to fix this right now, but you should keep in mind that asp.net gets more and more painful the further you stray from doing things the way it wants you to. I think it would be worth working out how to add these new options from the codebehind.

Comment: too much asp.net?? is that possible? ;)

Comment: asp.net considered harmful? :P

Answer (score 0):

try this code
 `Request.Form[Control.UniqueID]`